# Which Built-in C# Exception is used for check deleted item in the list

Tags: c#, exception

I am new to Programming and I built a simple console-based shopping list project which can add, remove and delete items, that works well but I am having some issues. If I tried to delete "mobile" from the list which is not actually added in the list but yet my app shows a message that mobile is successfully deleted, is there any built-in exception to prevent this exception or I have to write my own exception? Here my code

```
 public void MyMethod()
    {
        var itemList = new List<string>();
        int choices;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Shopping list:\n1. Add to list\n2. Remove from list\n3. List the items on the shopping list\n4. Exit");
            choices = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
           
                if (choices == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nWhat would you like to add in the list?");
                    string itemAdded = Console.ReadLine();

                try
                {
                    if (itemAdded == "null" || itemAdded == "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("you add nothing!!!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        itemList.Add(itemAdded);
                        Console.WriteLine(itemAdded + " is added to the list");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw ;
                }

                }

                else if (choices == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nWhat would you like to remove from the list?");
                    string itemToRemove = Console.ReadLine();




                try
                {
                    if (itemToRemove == "null" || itemToRemove == "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("you removed nothing");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        itemList.Remove(itemToRemove);
                        Console.WriteLine(itemToRemove + " is successfully removed from your list");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
                
               
                }

                else if (choices == 3)
                {
                    foreach (string item in itemList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                }

                else if (choices == 4)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("please enter valid choice!!!");
                }

        
        


        }


    }
```

Comment: No exceptions are thrown. `itemList.Remove(itemToRemove);` will return `false` if the item was not found [Check the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Note that there is no need to `try/catch` the methods `Add()` and `Remove()`, they don't throw exceptions

Comment: well in my case it is not returned false if the item is not found, do I need to change something?

Comment: can you please guide me then on how to handle that item not found thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - no exception will be thrown because exceptions aren't for this. Remove method returns boolean value. If a item has been deleted, then Remove will return true. False otherwise.

A little longer answer:
DO NOT use exceptions for that kind of work. They aren't created for that reason.
Exceptions are for "not expected" situations. For example - write to file when you don't have priviledges to do so.

Or maybe you expect that user will enter a number, but instead he enters a word. These are examples of exceptional situations. So use exceptions only in that case. Anywhere that you can use `if` or check by any other means if a operation can be done/was successful, use other means.